# Environment variables for React Application at runtime

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables, cloud-foundry

I have a React Application to be deployed to Cloud Foundry. I want to segregate dev, stage and prod. The issue is React provides `.env.development` for `react-scripts start` and `.env.production` for `react-scripts build`.

I want a solution to have 3 separate environments at runtime (with `npm build`)

I have added `app-config.js`:

```js
const SPACE_NAME_JSON = process.env.VCAP_APPLICATION
const SPACE_NAME = JSON.parse(SPACE_NAME_JSON).space_name

if (SPACE_NAME.match(/development/)) {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development'
} else if (SPACE_NAME.match(/stage/)) {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'stage'
}
} else if (SPACE_NAME.match(/production/)) {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'
}

console.log(`${process.env.NODE_ENV}`)
```

`package.json`: `build": " react-scripts build && cp app-config.js ./build"`

And injecting the script at runtime in `public/index`

```
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/app-config.js">
</script>
```

But after running the application, `process.env.NODE_ENV` gives `production` instead of `development` for development environment. This means it defaults to CRA's environment.

Is there a way to do this without ejecting webpack. (Since webpack is happening build time, but the application fetches detail at runtime.

Comment: I think I read that NODE_ENV is read-only. Take a look [here](https://medium.com/@hasniarif/how-to-handle-runtime-environment-variables-with-react-ec809cb07831)

Answer (score 0):

You can either write scripts to alter your files before serving follow - https://dev.to/akdevcraft/react-runtime-variables-49dc, or use a package which does that https://github.com/andrewmclagan/react-env

Sample code would be in lines of

```
// .env file
# .env
REACT_APP_NEXT="Next.js"
REACT_APP_CRA="Create React App"
REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE="1234"

// Your code
import env from "@beam-australia/react-env";

export default (props) => (
  <div>
    <small>
      Works in the browser: <b>{env("CRA")}</b>.
    </small>
    <small>
      Also works for server side rendering: <b>{env("NEXT")}</b>.
    </small>
    <form>
      <input type="hidden" defaultValue={env("NOT_SECRET_CODE")} />
    </form>
    <small>
      Entire safe environment:
      <pre>
        <code>{{JSON.stringify(env())}}</code>
      </pre>
    </small>
  </div>
);

// package.json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-env --env APP_ENV -- next start" // where .env.${APP_ENV}
  }
  ...
}
```

Few other configuration steps are needed, which you could find in the package help